# $L^{2}(\mathbb R)$- norm of entire function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function defined by $$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{z^{2}}{a_{n}^{2}}\bigg),\qquad z\in \mathbb C$$
where $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers, determined so that the  infinite product above defines an entire function. How can we compute the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{2}dx$$
where $x$ is real. Or at least finding an upper bound for it (if it is finite)?

Comment: Do you even know of an example where the integral is finite? I can't, off the top of my head.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I don't know, but I think it may depend on the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ ! So if this s the case, and the value of the integral depends on $\{a_{n}\}$, what conditions we must have?

Comment: @Harald: We have $\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$.

Comment: @timur: Nice example!

Comment: So, what about evaluating the above integral? any idea!

Comment: Do you assume that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$?

Comment: @Norbert: Oh of course, since if not then the zeros of $f$ have a limit point, and so $f=0$, since it is entire.

Comment: More generally if $\sum_n 1/a_n^2 < \infty$, the infinite product converges uniformly on compact sets to an entire function whose zeros are $\pm a_n$.

Comment: So it looks that there is no general method to evaluate that integration?!

Comment: At least, nobody here can think of a method. Which doesn't mean there isn't one. A couple of observations: As noted by Robert Israel, the convergence of the product has to do with the convergence of a sum, i.e., it has to do with the asymptotic behaviour of the sequence $(a_n)$. But by adding just one more factor to timur's example, I can destroy the finiteness of the integral, which shows that this does not relate well to asymptotic behaviours of $(a_n)$. I think this is likely a quite hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

I searched infinite products, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html. Consider $$cos(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2(2n-1)^2}\right).$$ 
Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |cos(x)|^2 dx=\infty.$$ So I don't think an upper bound can be found.